# Add tooltip on D3s x axis tick labels

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am using the `d3.svg.axis()` function in order to draw the x axis of my barchart. As the labels on the axis can be very long, I need to cut them (to let's say four letters) and display the rest as tooltip. I would like to make use of `svg:title`, as the browser will take care of displaying the tooltip then.
Any idea how I can achieve this? How can I add a title element on each label on the x axis ticks?

Many Thanks!

Comment: make a fiddle with your sample data, then we could work on it, and give it to you. In xAxis ticks we can do there.

Answer (score 2):

Should be as simple as:

```
// tooltip
d3.selectAll('.x.axis>.tick') // gs for all ticks
  .append('title') // append title with text
  .text(function(d){
    return d;
});
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/dfGLP0f8ir0waUogRW3M?p=preview).